# Как выполнить код из PHP файла внутри HTML

Tags: php, html

есть отдельный файл data_loader.php и есть html'ка view.html, как сделать так чтобы код из первого файла выполнился во втором?

Comment: такое нельзя сделать, если нет специальной конфигурации на сервере, чтоб html поддерживал php

Comment: Дайте ссылку на ресурс

Comment: https://encodable.com/parse_html_files_as_php/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Таким оброзом, на случай что ваш `html` в файле 'php'

```
<div> Hello World <?=$text;?></div>

<div> Hello world   
    <?php 
     echo $text;
    ?>
</div>
```

Если у вас файлы с разшерением `.html` надо сделать чтоб эти файлы поддерживали `php`.
прописываем это в `.htaccess`

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html
```

Comment: А вы бы не могли дать ссылку на какой-нибудь ресурс?

Comment: https://www.rssinclude.com/blog/36_how_to_run_php_scripts_in_html_or_htm_files

Comment: все гуд только есть проблемка, в результате работы скрипта выходя ромбики с вопросами? Как такое исправить?

Comment: Проследите что ваш фаил `utf-8`

Comment: именно файл с расширением .php должен быть UTF-8?

Comment: Может быть и другим, но если у вас все файлы `utf-8` то лучше сделать `utf-8`

Answer (score 1):

C условием что ваш файл имеет расширение `PHP (.php)` , например

```
<div>
<?php
/*Тут ваш PHP код */
?>
</div>
```

Если вам необходимо подключить файл, вы должны поментять расширение вашего view.html на view.php и в место для вставки написать

```
<?php
include('data_loader.php'); 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<head></head>
<body class="page_bg">
   Hello, today is <?php echo date('l, F jS, Y'); ?>.
</body>
</html>
```